# Issue Case Expression in store procedure of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am facing problem in store procedure of mysql.
    mainly i am facing CASE problem Those change the result.But i want choice result according call Like if i want table order according to id or name or class. So i implement CASE Expression. But not find result properly

**store procedure bellow**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StudentTablePagination
(

      IN Class NVARCHAR(50) ,
      IN Name NVARCHAR(50),
      IN StartRecord INT,
      IN PageSize INT,
      IN SortColumn NVARCHAR(20),
      IN SortOrder NVARCHAR(4)
)
BEGIN
  IF SortOrder = 'ASC' 
  Then
     SELECT  id from lakes where name like CONCAT('%',Name,'%') AND  class like 
     CONCAT('%',Class,'%')
     ORDER BY  (
       CASE SortColumn
       WHEN 'name' THEN lakes.name
       WHEN 'state' THEN lakes.state
       ELSE id END
    ) Asc 
    LIMIT StartRecord, PageSize;

 ELSEIF SortOrder = 'DESC' 
 Then
    SELECT  id from lakes where name like CONCAT('%',Name,'%') AND  class like 
    CONCAT('%',Class,'%')
    ORDER BY  (
      CASE SortColumn
      WHEN 'name' THEN lakes.name
      WHEN 'state' THEN lakes.state
      ELSE id END
    )  DESC LIMIT StartRecord , PageSize;
 END IF;
END
```

Call:

```
CALL StudentTablePagination('','', 0,10,'id','asc')
```

and Result:

```
id
10
100
1000
```

But Result Require:

```
id
1
2
3
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what problem you think you're trying to solve.

Comment: You can't use variables in the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @Strawberry when i apply ORDER BY id then not give proper result and other ORDER BY name then give proper result

Comment: @Barmar If i remove CASE Expression then working accordingly with variable in the LIMIT cluse

Comment: Can you create a SQLFiddle with sample data?

Comment: I suspect that you're approaching the problem (whatever it is) from the wrong end